# cannot update image

Tags: java, image, caching

Here's my App : First, we have to upload an image, then when we click SEARCH .. `JLabel` on the app will display icon that created from `new File("gambar/HistoJPG/sample.jpeg")`.

When the reset button is clicked, the image and the `sample.jpeg` will be deleted.

But when I upload the next image, the new `sample.jpg` will be created again and be displayed. but the app still display the old `sample.jpg`, not the new one, even though old `sample.jpg` has been deleted.

Here's some of my code

```
 histoQ.setIcon(new ImageIcon("gambar/HistoJPG/sample.jpeg"));
```

Here's the button reset action :

```
breset.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        imgLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/image/blank.jpg"));
        File fildel = new File("gambar/HistoJPG/sample.jpeg");
        fildel.delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Verify that the the file has been delete.  `File#delete` will return false if Java was unable to delete the file.  You can also use `File#exists` to check to see if the file still exists.  You also reference two different (I assume) labels, `histoQ` and `imgLabel` one might assume you're referencing the wrong label

Comment: imgLabel is for displaying image.. it's not the problem..
to display sample.jpg is on histoQ label...
i've checked, deleting works fine
when we uploading new image, it's automatically create new sample.jpg..the app created sample.jpg.. but the picture that display in histoQ is still the old one even the sample.jpg has changed to the new one. Help me please..

Comment: It sounds like a caching issue with `ImageIcon` (not surprisingly).  What I think is happening, when you ask Java to read the image again, it looks at the file name a says "Oh, I've already loaded this image" and returns the cached pixel data for it. The suggests are to either call `ImageIcon#getImage#flush` to flush the cached data or try using the `ImageIO` API

Comment: thank you.. it works now.. using flush().. :)